# What does "il fait" mean?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

I came about sentences having "Il fait". What does it mean?

For instance, what does "Il fait gris" mean?

Comment: What about [looking  in a dictionary first](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/il%20fait%20gris) for vocabulary?

Answer (score 2):

It translates to :

> It is grey. (Outside)

*Il fait* can be translated often into *It is* when used that way.